# XSL-FO Stylesheet template to generate a PDF manual

Tags: pdf, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I want to create a user manual in A4 format for my programming tool, much like the example [here](http://www.doku.info/doku_article_510.html). Is there any clean, well formatted open-src documentation XSL-FO Stylesheet that I can use as my template? It should have support to include

- tables
- code samples
- images

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [DocBook](http://docbook.sourceforge.net/), powerful markup language for technical documentation.
For example, [Special DocBook features](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/FeaturesPart.html), [user-configurable parameters for XSL-FO output](http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/doc/fo/index.html).

For using out of the box just apply `docbook/fo/docbook.xsl` to your valid docbook xml file.